# Калькулятор на JavaScript | проблема с +, *, : в начале строки

Tags: javascript, html

Я делал калькулятор на JavaScript и столкнулся  проблемой, что если первым в нём ввести "+" или " * " или " : ", то они должны стереться или просто не вводится. В голове есть идея как это сделать, но никак не получается

Вот код калькулятора:

```js
function insert(num) {
    document.form.textview.value = document.form.textview.value + num;
    let exp = document.form.textview.value;
}

function equal() {
    let exp = document.form.textview.value;
    if (exp) {
        document.form.textview.value = eval(exp);
    }
}

function clean() {
    document.form.textview.value = '';
}

function back() {
    let exp = document.form.textview.value;
    document.form.textview.value = exp.substring(0, exp.length-1)
}
```

Comment: И какая идея есть у вас в голове?

Comment: разобрать строку и удалять первый символ, если превым будет +, * или :

Comment: если вы используете input для ввода значений из клавиатуры то можете это сделать через регулярное выражение, которое будет запрещать пользователю ввести определенные символые первыми. Если вы делаете ввод через кнопки то можете добавить проверку на пустоту строки, т.е. если строка пустая то не добавлять плюс и тд

Comment: Функция, которая отвечает за ввод символов, должна проверять, что уже введено... `if( ваш_input.value.length == 0 ) return;` Без HTML и общего кода сложно точнее ответить.